# Basket of goods in SF

Tags: science-fiction, economy

I'm creating a SF-cyberpunk universe. The action is set somewhere in 3600, 1600 years after today. Humanity has colonized several hundred star systems around Milky Way. Even thought there was no technological singularity, typical life on regularly urbanized planets (where its where history is taking place) is near post scarcity like.

A problem I've encountered is showing my players (as the universe is for a RPG, at least for now) how much stuff costs. By stuff I mean everything, from single bread through machine guns and cars, to buying planets or Star Systems; it is also how much you earn/pay in certain professions. 
What I need is **some sort of comprehensive list of things that should have an assigned price to create some idea how much everything cost.**

P.S. I'm not asking for prices itself, I'll value it by myself.

EDIT 
You guys missed my point when I wrote a "post scarcity like". I didn't wanted to be universe where everything is almost free, it would be to much hassle explaining and playing with this setup. My bad for not making it clear, sorry.
Instead what I want is universe where most of daily products are "only" extremely cheap.

Comment: Please clarify "Post Scarcity Like".  If it is truly post scarcity, then all basic consumables are effectively cost free and the idea of working for a wage is just an eccentric way to obtain the use of more luxury items than would otherwise be yours for the asking.  Also, in a post scarcity world, ownership would not be a thing.  You wouldn't own a planet, but you might have rights to a few acres of land where you experiment with farming for fun.  Also, firearms might not be a thing since their primary use is to obtain other peoples stuff which you no longer need because you have your own.

Comment: @HenryTaylor I know that basic commodity are extremly cheap, and I'll include when setting prices. Only people who want something more then basic would work anyway. Also, why would ownershipd perish? It make no sense.

Comment: I'm taking my understanding of Post Scarcity from Cory Doctorow's book, "Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom".  In that story, the society makes optimal use of its available resources by having everyone share.  You don't own a car; rather when you need to get somewhere that public transport can't reach, you take any of the parked vehicles which are waiting to be borrowed.  It is just one short book, so the details of how the rest of the system works aren't spelled out, but it appears that ownership is de-emphasized and in its place, right-to use is abundant.

Comment: @HenryTaylor So you are using different then mine, I've got mine from partly wikipedia. "Post-scarcity is a theoretical economic situation in which most goods can be produced in great abundance with minimal human labor needed, so that they become available to all very cheaply or even freely."

Comment: An interesting concept for pricing goods in an advanced Sf civilisation, where energy and thus most goods are extremely cheap is to base the pricing on the waste heat production. Ultimately it is the bottle neck for K2+ civilisations.

Comment: OK, nitpick - the premise doesn't sound like cyberpunk. The genre is defined by the clash of futuristic tech (cyber-) and how society is still bad or even worse off (-punk). There are many ways to explore that but at its heart, the cyberpunk genre is about a dark future where tech either didn't solve our problems or worsened them. The term "post scarcity" doesn't seem like it belongs. And the *very* distant future makes showing the conflict between tech and societal problems really hard, as cyberpunk thrives on transplanting current day situations or concerns into a dark future.

Comment: That's why I wrote"post scarcity like". I wanted to capture image of dirt cheap basic commodities, but more luxurious would be much much expensive. I don't think it blocks all cyberpunk's problems; we have there things like almighty corporations, serious privacy problems, trans-humanism and others.

Comment: Also, when I'm thankful of your concerns about realibilty of this world, it wasn't any point of question.

Comment: @VLAZ it's not so difficult to design a "post-scarcity cyberpunk". Imagine a world where food, clothing and basic necessities cost nothing, but they are distributed by the AI which is controlled by corporations. Regular people live squalid conditions in mega-cities, and have no real way to improve their lives.

Comment: @Alexander there is a short story called *The MIdas Plague* where in the future we've found way to produce items so cheaply, that the entire society flipped its approach to consumerism. Everybody is a rampant consumer - clothes, houses, appliances, etc - you have it all. But it's *a great burden*. The reward for consuming a lot is to allow you to slow down. Perfect retirement is just a small house with all the essentials and living a simple life. So, yes you can have a cyberpunk post-scarcity. But my point was more about *both* aspects combined - the far future, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as the "[Basket of goods](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/basket_of_goods.asp)" and is designed to represent the things ordinary people buy on a day to day basis.

> A basket of goods refers to a fixed set of consumer products and services valued on an annual basis. The basket is used to track inflation in a specific market or country. The goods in the basket are often adjusted periodically to account for changes in consumer habits. The basket of goods is used primarily to calculate the consumer price index (CPI).

Of course the basket isn't going to contain quite the same goods in the future as it does now, though many of the food items remain relatively constant, in the UK there are about 700 items on the list.

The [information on the list and the reasons things are chosen](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices/articles/ukconsumerpriceinflationbasketofgoodsandservices/2019) is a long read, but if you really want to go so far down this rabbit hole then all the information is there.

[UK 2019 list (xlsx)](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=%2Feconomy%2Finflationandpriceindices%2Fdatasets%2Fconsumerpriceinflationbasketofgoodsandservices%2Ftablesandannexes2019/combinedtablescpibasket2019.xlsx)

> [image: UK 2019 basket of goods]

You did ask for comprehensive. Ok you can't buy a machine gun in the UK, but everything else is there.

Comment: Well, something like that, but more cut out for future world, and definitely less focus on many small food stuff. But it gives me idea to change question title, so thanks.

Comment: @Guywithjewels'names for for a future setting much of it remains the same apart from the "leisure goods" section which is tech dependent.

Comment: One thing I would add to this great answer is that higher-tech, "equivalent" quality items tend to drive out higher ones over time. So : steak is replaced by an equivalent weight of burger, then by an equivalent weight of soy; or in your high-tech world nutrient goo.

Answer (score 6):

**No money.  Barter.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_red_paperclip

> One red paperclip is a website created by Canadian blogger Kyle
>   MacDonald, who bartered his way from a single red paperclip to a house
>   in a series of fourteen online trades over the course of a year.
>   ... Better. His site
>   received a considerable amount of notice for tracking the
>   transactions. "A lot of people have been asking how I've stirred up so
>   much publicity around the project, and my simple answer is: 'I have no
>   idea'", he told the BBC.

There is no money in your world because it is post-scarcity - you can have what you need.  But unusual and cool stuff is still scarce.  Since there is no money, the only way to get cool stuff is to trade comparably cool stuff for it.

This will be more fun for your players too.  Some stuff might be unusual - found relics and one of a kind items.  There might be IOUs for services of various sorts or players could trade their own services.  Some stuff might be illegal or dangerous.  Ideally if you have a dangerous item you get it off your hands quick and covert it to something comparably valuable but less dangerous.

Your players might know of one or more fences or barter proxies where they can unload items.  There could be a night market they visit to try and trade up.  Or Bartertown!  Leave weapons at the door, of course.

---

This would not be suitable for a computer game at all.  But for a D&D style game with live people interacting it would be fun, and save the time of creating a huge list of stuff that will mostly never have any part in the game.

Comment: I've edited question, you might want to revisit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**"Post-scarcity" really throwing a wrench into the available approaches.**

Normally, you would follow @Separatrix advice and compile some futuristic "basket of goods". But if this is a truly post-scarcity society, this list would be meaningless, as most of the items on it would become negligibly cheap.

What you need to do is to try to think through you society's economy. What is abundant? What is still scarce? This should become a basis for the "post-scarcity basket of goods". Here are some ideas of what might still be valuable:

1. Land, particularly the land in desired locations. This will drive up not just the cost of housing, but make all local services in those locations not cheap. Think about a city like Hong Kong or San Francisco. What can be cheaply delivered by a drone, and what has to be bought locally?
2. Human services. Robots are replacing humans right now, and they should replace even more of us in the year 3600, but you have to draw the line somewhere. Would people still want to use human doctors, teachers, hairdressers? All of the human provided services will be not cheap.
3. Taxes and fees. Charges imposed by society may become the main barrier for over-consumption. Suppose, you can buy a car for a pocket change. You can buy a dozen cars. But registration fees can make owning even one car problematic. Or you can get a truckload of bread for free - but pay a steep fine for the waste.

Comment: I've edited question, you might want to revisit your answer.